# /me/invitable_friends does not return all friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

According to https://www.facebook.com/neubert/friends I have 209 friends but `/me/invitable_friends?limit=10000` returns only 190. How come? Am I doing something wrong? Is there some sort of privacy setting that these 19 friends likely have that's making it so I can't see them?

I haven't created an exhaustive list of who I'm not seeing with `/me/invitable_friends` but one of the names has a hyphen in it for whatever that's worth (eg. Elaine Smith-Jones or some such). idk if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/invitable_friends

> returns a ranked list of a person's friends who do not play the game

Maybe those other friends are already authorized? Nevertheless, you don´t need ALL friends for invitiable friends anyway, that endpoint is not there to read all the friends of a user but to get a ranked list to invite them to your game.

Also, not everyone got the platform enabled, so they will not show up in any result but the total amount of friends should be correct.

Comment: They're not. It's an app that's in development and I'm the only user. I'm trying to make a quiz whereby people can guess the names of their friends. To my knowledge there is no other endpoint that I can use. `/user/friends` returns a list of people who've installed the app. Per that you'd think that `/user/friends` and `/me/invitable_friends` would equal your friend count but it doesn't. And regardless of what endpoint(s) I should be using I'm still curious about why `/me/invitable_friends` isn't returning everyone it ought to be. If it's a privacy setting which privacy setting is it?

Comment: i´ve added another possibility. but still, invitable_friends is for inviting friends only, not for getting a list of all friends to do something else.

Answer (score 1):

Graph API /user/taggable_friends - Facebook Developers if you just need to fetch all of users friends you can try this...me/taggable_friends

Comment: that endpoint is ONLY for tagging friends and needs to get reviewed. if you "just need to fetch all user friends", it´s the wrong way. there is NO legal possibility to "just fetch all user friends" with v2.0+.